# How I run my Cordova application in the real device?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, device

when i run my project ionic cordova application in the real device i found this error :

Application Error

network error found (http:/192.168.1.9:8100)

Comment: I execute this command in the terminal " ionic run android -l -c"

Comment: -l is for live reload. It seems that the served didn't start correctly

Comment: i resolve this error ,when i execute the last command sauf -l

Comment: thanks @jcesarmobile ,now i found another error ((error initializing cordova :class not found)]

Comment: i resolve this error just --- try this below
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android :D